# How can I mix parent POMs in a Maven multi-module build?

Tags: maven-2, relative-path, multi-module, parent-pom

I have a Maven multi-module project and I need two different parent POMs in this build. The first one is the real parent POM for most modules in the project but one module is a demo project which uses the parent POM of a completely different project (because it's a demo how to use my project to generate code for the second project).

The build works but I get a warning:

```
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for my_project:my_project.demo:jar:5.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'parent.relativePath' points at my_project:parent instead of other_project:parent, please verify your project structure @ line 5, column 10
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
```

Since `other_project` is not really a module of my build, it can be anywhere. This means I can't give a relative path.

How can I fix this warning?

Comment: It exactly states what you described which is from Maven point of view not correct. If you have a kind of a demonstration project simply put it into a different location like src/main/demonstration and may be change your packaging or to your project site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution in this case is to set the `relativePath` to nothing to overwrite the default `../pom.xml`:

```
<relativePath/>
```

- [Discussion](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/mvn-3-parent-relativePath-problem-but-no-relativePath-element-tp3278463p3278513.html)
- [MNG-4687 - Maven should not warn about incorrect parent path when no relativePath is specified](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-4687))
- [MNG-2026 - Document how parent-child POM relationships, , and  works](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-2026)